# Disable Equation Numbering While Checking for Empty Text

Tags: spacing, macros, conditionals

I have cases where certain text may end up being empty based on various flag settings.  Thus, I adapted solutions from
[Proper way to detect empty/blank text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/proper-way-to-detect-empty-blank-text)
and
[Missing Item number in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/missing-item-number-in-enumerate)
to typset the content into a box and check if the width of the box is zero.

Since, I retypeset the content (instead of using the `\savebox` I measured), the equation numbering is incorrect:

---

[image]

---

I thougth of two "simple" solutions:

1. Manually set `\measuring@true` and
2. redefine `\label` during the empty check.

Sadly, these turn out to be so simple that they do *not* work!!  The frist results in an error condition, and the second seems to have no effect.

### Notes:

- In this MWE I could reuse the `\savebox` instead of re-typesetting it, but that is not possible in my actual use case as I disable other macros (which do not impact the check for empty text) during the "measuring" phase.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
%% Adapted from egreg's solutions at 
%%     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/proper-way-to-detect-empty-blank-text
%%     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/missing-item-number-in-enumerate
\newsavebox{\@NonEmptyTestBox}%
\newcommand{\DoIfNonEmptyText}[1]{% Note: Actually takes 2 parameters
    \begingroup%
    \EnableCheckingForEmptyText% 
    \savebox{\@NonEmptyTestBox}{\hfuzz=1000pt\everypar{}\vbox{#1}}% 
    \ifdim\wd\@NonEmptyTestBox=\z@\relax% 
            \DisableCheckingForEmptyText%
            \endgroup\expandafter\@gobble%
        \else%
            \DisableCheckingForEmptyText%
            \endgroup\expandafter\@firstofone%
        \fi%
    }%

%\newtoggle{CheckingForEmptyText}% <-- Commented out as it is not used in MWE, but is in actual use case.
\newcommand*{\EnableCheckingForEmptyText}{%
    %\toggletrue{CheckingForEmptyText}% 
    %\measuring@true% <-- Error: "Multiple \label's:"
    \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{}% <--- Seems to have no effect
}%
\newcommand*{\DisableCheckingForEmptyText}{%
    %\togglefalse{CheckingForEmptyText}%
    %\measuring@false%
}%
\makeatother 


\newcommand*{\EquationsText}{%
    Some interesting equations include
    \begin{align}
        F &= ma \label{eqn:newton} \\
        E &= mc^2 \label{eqn:einstein}
    \end{align}
    But there are others as well.%
}


\begin{document}
\DoIfNonEmptyText{\EquationsText}{%
    \section{Equations}
    \EquationsText%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be it's answered in your other questions (in that case, sorry for asking again), but why exactly do you need boxes? Couldn't you do some `\edef` expansion and check if it's empty, or a full expansion (with ``\romannumeral-`\Q`` trick) and check if the result is empty?

Comment: @Manuel: Such a solution did not show up at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/proper-way-to-detect-empty-blank-text, where I had attempted to make a MWE. Perhaps you could post one there.

Comment: Too old to answer it probably, but, in any case, if you separated “value” from “output” (in that question, for instance, the `\xspace` inside `\SetName` should not be there, and be only in the output macro `\ShowNameandAdress`), so that it's easy to check if the variable is empty or not, you would have much simple macros to compare to empty or blank strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some difficulties in understanding the reason for such a macro, but the customer's always right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
%% Adapted from egreg's solutions at 
%%     http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/proper-way-to-detect-empty-blank-text
%%     http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/missing-item-number-in-enumerate
\newsavebox{\@NonEmptyTestBox}
\newcommand{\DoIfNonEmptyText}[1]{% Note: Actually takes 2 parameters
  \begingroup
  \let\stepcounter\@gobble
  \let\label@in@display\@gobble % maybe other macros, such as \label
  \savebox{\@NonEmptyTestBox}{\hfuzz=1000pt\everypar{}\vbox{#1}}% 
  \ifdim\wd\@NonEmptyTestBox=\z@
    \endgroup\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \endgroup\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}

%\newtoggle{CheckingForEmptyText}% <-- Commented out as it is not used in MWE
\makeatother 


\newcommand*{\EquationsText}{%
  Some interesting equations include
  \begin{align}
    F &= ma \\% \label{eqn:newton} \\
    E &= mc^2 \label{eqn:einstein}
  \end{align}
  But there are others as well.
}
\newcommand{\EmptyEq}{\sbox0{whatever}}

\begin{document}
\DoIfNonEmptyText{\EquationsText}{%
    \section{Equations}
    \EquationsText
}

\DoIfNonEmptyText{\EmptyEq}{%
    \section{Equations}
    \EmptyEq
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great for the given MWE. But, what about other numbered equation environments? Is there not a more general solution to this?

Comment: @PeterGrill I forgot to remove that line, remaining from an earlier experiment.

Comment: @PeterGrill You're right! I was thinking to `\addtocounter`!