# Missing Item number in enumerate while checking for empty text

Tags: conditionals, boxes

This is a follow-up to [Missing Item number in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/missing-item-number-in-enumerate).  Similar issue is reported, but *only* under very specific circumstances. In the prior question, the macro `DoIfNonEmptyText` is defined which executes its second parameter if `#1` is non-empty. It has worked fine for me for many cases, but there are a few specific cases where I get

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

In the MWE below, the first `\DoIfNonEmptyText{\ExampleVar}{}` is the problem and results in this error message. In actual use case #2 in this call executes other code, but does not produce any output. By disabling the above error message, I get the output shown:

[image]

Notice the double item numbers. even though there is only one `\item` in the `enumerate` environment.
In this specific case, this problem does not show up if:

- `wrapfigure` is not used, or
- the display math in `enumerate` is replaced by inline math.

#### Question:

What changes do I need to make to the `DoIfNonEmptyText` resolve this issue?

#### References:

- [Missing Item number in enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/missing-item-number-in-enumerate)
- [How to make itemize/enumerate/description environment robust to missing \item elements?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86547/how-to-make-itemize-enumerate-description-environment-robust-to-missing-item-el)

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\makeatletter
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86547
\newcommand\IgnoreMissingItemError{\let\@noitemerr\relax}

\newcommand{\DescriptionVar}{}%
\newcommand{\SetDescription}[1]{\renewcommand{\DescriptionVar}{#1}}

\newcommand{\ExampleVar}{}%
\newcommand{\SetExample}[1]{\renewcommand{\ExampleVar}{#1}}

\newsavebox{\@NonEmptyTestBox}
\newcommand{\DoIfNonEmptyText}[1]{% Actually takes two parameters
  %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57358/4301 (replaced sbox0 with \@NonEmptyTestBox)
  \begingroup
  \savebox{\@NonEmptyTestBox}{%
      \vbox{\everypar{}#1}%
  }%
  \ifdim\wd\@NonEmptyTestBox=\z@\relax
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\PrintBody}{%
    \DescriptionVar%
    \IgnoreMissingItemError%
    \DoIfNonEmptyText{\ExampleVar}{}% <-- This is problem. Needs \IgnoreMissingItemError
    \DoIfNonEmptyText{\ExampleVar}{%
        \medskip\par
        \textbf{Example:}
        \smallskip\par
        \begin{adjustwidth}{1.0cm}{0.0pt} 
            \ExampleVar
        \end{adjustwidth}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\SetDescription{%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4.0cm}%
        \fbox{xxxxxx}%
    \end{wrapfigure}%
    Some Text
}%
\SetExample{%    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \[ x + y \]
    \end{enumerate}%
}
\PrintBody
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you expect this to actually work or are you just asking why it fails in the particular way it fails? Because I don't think it's reasonable to expect sensible output, but it does seem weird the output is not sensible in this specific way.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, I want this to work. Why do you think it's not reasonable to expect sensible ouptut?  Works fine if you don't use warpfigure in the first section or if you use inline math instead of display math. I want the examples typset only for the case where they produce output.

Comment: Because `wrapfig` doesn't like being too close to a list (or a section).

Comment: @cfr: Seems to work fine if display math is used in the example. Do I need to add a `\par` after `wrapfigure`? And, how does `wragfigure` effect the `\DoIfNonEmptyText` macro?

Comment: `wrapfig` 'subverts' `\@setpar` and `\everypar`. `wrapfigure` changes `\par` .... And you're using `\everypar` etc. I don't know it's a problem. It just rang alarm bells. And `adjustwidth` is implemented as a list? Though I'm not sure that itself would be problematic.

Comment: The `everypar{}` was needed as per egreg's solution at the earlier referenced question. There should be some reset I can do after I am done with the `wrapfigure`

Comment: Right now, `\savebox{\@NonEmptyTestBox}{%
      \vbox{\everypar{}#1}%
  }%` happens when `wrapfigure`'s definition of `\everypar` is in effect. It's reset by `\medskip\par`. At least, I *think* so. I don't understand this stuff anything like as well as virtually everybody else. But `\show\everypar` shows the toks register change. (If that's the term: `\toks12`, `\toks17`.) Or is that normal?