# Saving a list in a re-usable box

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, boxes

Pardon me if this is a dumb question, but I am a bit rusty about this.

I want to store a list like one generated by the `enumerate` environment in a re-usable box that I may re-use within a `TikZ` picture and elsewhere.

In a manner of speaking, `fancybox.sty` does this with an actual framed box rather than a re-usable box.

Naively, I am looking to do something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\enumbox}
\sbox{\enumbox}{%
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Title
    \item Abstract
    \item Keywords
    \item Outline
\end{enumerate}
}
{\centering\usebox{\enumbox}}
\end{document}
```

Of course, the above does not work because it is neither a `parbox` nor an `lrbox`.

Is there any package that does this? Otherwise, what do I have to do to get what I am seeking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to save the `enumerate` contents [in a `\vbox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46480/16595):

```
\setbox\enumbox\vbox{% …
```

Though, the `\centering` won’t work because the box is—due to `enumerate`’s nature— `\linewidth` wide.
Using it without `\centering` results in an `overfull \hbox` because the paragraph indention is inserted as usual.

#### Solution A

It seems, that in your case you simply could define a macro as

```
\newcommand*{\enummacro}{\begin{enumerate} … \end{enumerate}}
```

and use that inside a TikZ node. Advantage: The node would not be `\linewidth` wide but only as wide as you would have specified.

#### Solution B

You could measure the width of the list elements (assuming that they all fit on one line width-wise).

Here, I opted for an easier list defining and processing solution, namely

```
\newcommand*{\mylist}{Title,Abstract,Keywords,Outline}
```

The `\mylist` macro only contains the comma-separated elements.

The `\getWidthOf` macro needs `\tikz@textfont` and the smuggle macro to be usable inside a `tikzpicture` (no warranties here).

#### Solution C

As the `enumerate` environment introduces vertical and horizontal space which with I do not want to deal and also because the following looks better and is easier to maintain, yet another solution but with a simple `tabular`.

### Code A (`enumerate` with guessed width)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\enummacro}{%
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Title
    \item Abstract
    \item Keywords
    \item Outline
\end{enumerate}}
\newsavebox\enumbox

\begin{document}
\setbox\enumbox\vbox{\enummacro}
\noindent\usebox\enumbox

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, text width=8em, align=center] {\enummacro};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (`enumerate` with guessed width)

[image]

### Solution B (properly measured `enumerate`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\mylist}{Title,Abstract,Keywords,Outline}
\newlength{\widthOfWidestElement}

\makeatletter
\def\qrr@smuggle@length@through@interruptpgfpicture#1\endpgfinterruptpicture{%
    \edef\@tempa{\the#1}%
    \expandafter\endpgfinterruptpicture\expandafter#1\@tempa}
\newcommand*{\getWidthOf}[1]{%
    \pgfinterruptpicture
    \setlength{\widthOfWidestElement}{0pt}%
    \@for\@element:=#1\do{%
        \sbox0{\tikz@textfont\@element}%
        \ifdim\wd0>\widthOfWidestElement\widthOfWidestElement=\wd0\fi
    }%
    \qrr@smuggle@length@through@interruptpgfpicture\widthOfWidestElement
    \endpgfinterruptpicture
    \advance\widthOfWidestElement\itemindent
    \advance\widthOfWidestElement\leftmargin
    \advance\widthOfWidestElement\rightmargin
}
\newcommand*{\makeEnumerate}[1]{%
    \enumerate % maybe better output with
               % \parskip\z@
        \@for\@element:=#1\do{%
            \item \@element
        }
    \endenumerate
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \getWidthOf{\mylist}
    \node[draw, text width=\widthOfWidestElement, align=center] {\makeEnumerate\mylist};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output B (properly measured `enumerate`)

[image]

### Code C (`tabular`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array}

\newcommand*{\mylist}{Title,Abstract,Keywords,Outline}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\makeFakeEnumerate}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\@temptabbody{}%
    \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
    \@for\@element:=#1\do{%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\@temptabbody\expandafter{\expandafter&\@element \\}}%
    \tabular{>{\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.}rl}
        \@temptabbody
    \endtabular
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] {\makeFakeEnumerate\mylist};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output C (`tabular`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have one question though. Is there any way to loop through the `enumerate` entries to get the longest so that the box width may be determined automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Would you be interesting in using `\newcommand*{\enummacro}{Title,Abstract,Keywords,Outline}` as a list which will be used to get measured *and* to set up the `enumerate` environment? What is your end goal here? Maybe you could use a `tabular` with two columns of which the last one is a line-breaking-disallowing `l` column.

Comment: Thank you for the `tabular` output C that mimics an `enumerate` environment but which is easy to maintain. I am using the `makeFakeEnumerate` command in a manuscript and the result here is exactly what I wanted: http://i.imgur.com/FKAosW9.png. I guess that I could adapt this to display bullet-points in a `makeFakeItemize` command as well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Unless there is a compelling reason to use a box, it is much simpler to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\enumbox{%
\enumerate
    \item test
    \item Abstract
    \item Keywords
    \item Outline
\endenumerate
}
\enumbox
\end{document}
```

If you want to center do this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\enumbox{%
\enumerate
    \item test
    \item Abstract
    \item Keywords
    \item Outline
\endenumerate
}
\lipsum[1]\centering
\fbox{\hbox to 3cm{\vbox{\enumbox}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the same question as above. Is there a way of determining the required box width (which is manually set to 3 cm here) by looping through the entries to find the longest? I looked at the `forloop` package but wasn't sure it was suited for this. I would like to automate this, please.

Comment: @chandra It is possible, will post a solution in the morning, as I am on the other side of the world:)