# TikZ: Flow Chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, lists, nodes, itemize

Kindly help this messy tikz flow chart.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=10em, text centered, fill=yellow!80]
\tikzstyle{mycircle} = [circle, draw, text width=7em, text centered, fill=red!30]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4.5cm, auto, >=stealth]
     \centering
\node [block](child){\par {Early life{\begin{itemize}
\item Genetic
\item Environmental
\end{itemize}}}};

\node [block] (psych)[right of = child]{\large {Psychoscial factors}{\begin{itemize}
\item life stress
\item Psychological stress
\item coping
\item social support
\end{itemize}}};

\node [block](physiology)[below of = psych]{Physiology {\begin{itemize}
\item Motility
\item Sensation
\item Inflammation
\item Altered bacterial
\item flora
\end{itemize}}};

\node [mycircle](FGID)[right of = physiology]{FGID};
%path
\draw[->](child)--(psych);
\draw[->] (child)--(physiology);
\draw[<->](psych)--(physiology);
\draw [<->](physiology)--(FGID);
\draw [<->](psych)--(FGID);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You shouln’t create a style `circle` which uses the shape `circle`. Either use a different name or or use `circle/.style={shape=circle}`. Also relevant: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372) and [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386). `\large` doesn’t take an argument, the correct use would be `{\large Physoscial factors}`. `<-->` isn’t correct. (Do you mean `<->`?)

Comment: edited to include your suggestion. did not understand the difference between right of= and right=of

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the things I already commented on, here are a few other things I’d consider:

Setting a fixed with makes the nodes having them the same width but also creates problem for very long words in the `itemize` environment. In addition to that the `itemize` environment introduces a rather high horizontal white space in front of the bullet. (Similar things happen in [Saving a list in a re-usable box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105987/16595).)

I would avoid `itemize` and reproduce the behavior with a simply `tabular` environment (see my answer on the linked question) which inserts the bullet on its own.

For a more pleasing output I center the first line (kind of a header, isn’t it?) and add additional vertical space. The `rectangle split` shape might help here.

The needed options are:

- `shape=rectangle split`,
- `rectangle split parts=2`: we want two parts,
- `rectangle split part align={center,left}`: the first part is centered, the second part is left-aligned.
- `rectangle split draw splits=false`: by default the shape has lines between the separate parts, this disables them.

In the second example, I have used [my `positioning-plus` library](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex) to place the `psych` and the `FGID` node vertically centered to the other nodes.

The first example needs the `positioning` library (which is loaded by `positioning-plus` so it is not loaded explicitly).

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,array}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning-plus,arrows,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    shape=rectangle split,
    draw,
    rectangle split part align={center,left},
    rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false},
  Circle/.style={shape=circle, draw, align=left}}
\newcommand*{\itemizeTabular}[2][l]{%
  \begin{tabular}{!{\kern\tabcolsep\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, >=stealth]
\node[block] (child) {%
  Early life\nodepart{two}
  \itemizeTabular{Genetic\\Environmental}};
\node[block, right=of child] (psych) {%
  Psychoscial factors\nodepart{two}
  \itemizeTabular{life stress\\Psychological stress\\coping\\social support}};
\node[block, below=of psych] (phys) {%
  Physiology\nodepart{two}
  \itemizeTabular{Motility\\Sensation\\Inflammation\\Altered bacterial\\flora}};

\node[Circle, right=of phys](FGID) {FGID};

\path[->] (child) edge (psych)
                  edge (phys);
\path[<->] (psych) edge (phys)
                   edge (FGID)
            (phys) edge (FGID);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, >=stealth]
\node[block] (psych) {%
  Psychoscial factors\nodepart{two}
  \itemizeTabular{life stress\\Psychological stress\\coping\\social support}};
\node[block, below=of psych] (phys) {%
  Physiology\nodepart{two}
  \itemizeTabular{Motility\\Sensation\\Inflammation\\Altered bacterial\\flora}};

\node[block,left=of (phys)(psych)] (child) {%
  Early life\nodepart{two}
  \itemizeTabular{Genetic\\Environmental}};

\node[Circle, right=of (phys)(psych)](FGID) {FGID};

\path[->] (child) edge (psych)
                  edge (phys);
\path[<->] (psych) edge (phys)
                   edge (FGID)
            (phys) edge (FGID);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image]

Comment: Would you like to comment out what these terms mean?     rectangle split part align={center,left},
    rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split draw splits=false},
Also on the difference between right=of and right of=

Comment: How can I put a text "Gut brain interaction " around arrow between psychosocial and physiology

Comment: is there a difference in ()--() and () edge()

Comment: @user34083 `--` and `edge` are very different. For once, `--` only draws a straight line whereas `edge` works with the same options as `to`. Furthermore, `edge`s are drawn separately (there are better examples to show this). `\path (a) edge (b) edge (c);` actually draws a line from `(a)` to `(b)` and from `(a)` to `(c)` (not from `(b)` to `(c)`). — How should the text `Gut brain interaction` be placed?

Comment: Gut brain interaction -vertically along the edge between physiology and psychosocial factors

Comment: Error: I can't find file `tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex' ...{positioning-plus,arrows,shapes.multipart}
Emergency stop ...{positioning-plus,arrows,shapes.multipart}

Comment: @user34083 `Gut brain interaction` nearly has enough room to place it vertically without the nodes, but anyhow you can simply add a node to the edge: `(node 1) edge node [options]{text} (node 2)`. — The `positioning-plus` library is not part of TikZ but my own, the link to is posted in the answer. Simply copy the file along your `.tex` or include it in the `texmf` path. Mind you, the file is not needed for the first TikZ picture but only for the second.