# How can I create two boxes in the same line

Tags: boxes, verbatim

How can I create two boxes in the same line with words in between(as the picture below which I made using MS-Word)? I tried `\makebox`, `\fbox` or `\minipage` and none of them seem to be working, maybe because I am using `verbatim` environment at the same time. I am trying to make a section illustrating how to type Chinese in LaTeX.

I have tried

```
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\end{verbatim}  
\end{minipage}
}
```

or any other possible combination of this three command but the typeset engine always give me errors says there is one extra `{` at the end of the code, even though it should be the right bracket of `\fbox`.
[image: The effect I want]

Comment: `tcolorbox` and its `listings` library can make such code boxes with basically any fancy decoration.

Comment: @Christian supplied you with a suggestion on how to solve your problem, however, if you want more extensive help with your question it would help if you could supply a MWE with what you have tried so far and to give us a starting point.

Comment: @Timm Thank you very much. I have already editted my question.

Comment: The problem isn't two boxes in the same line, it's putting verbatim inside a box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an easy-to-use application, just set these in a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Either
\begin{tabular}{ | @{\,} l @{\,} | }
  \hline
  \verb|\documentclass{article}| \\
  \verb|\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}| \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
or
\begin{tabular}{ | @{\,} l @{\,} | }
  \hline
  \verb|\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}| \\
  \verb|\begin{document}| \\
  \verb|\end{document}| \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}.

\end{document}
```

---

Another option using [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) to save the verbatim content and use it inside `\fbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{optA}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\begin{SaveVerbatim}{optB}
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\end{SaveVerbatim}

Either \fbox{\strut\BUseVerbatim{optA}} or \fbox{\strut\BUseVerbatim{optB}}.

\end{document}
```

`\strut`s ensure a consistent baseline with respect to the two verbatims.

Answer (score 7):

With a `tcblisting` from `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcblisting{mybox}[2][]{%
    nobeforeafter, listing only,
    box align=center,
    sharp corners, width=#2, notitle, size=fbox, #1}

\begin{document}

Either 
\begin{mybox}[after=\ ]{5cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\end{mybox} 
or 
\begin{mybox}[colback=white]{6cm}
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The background colour of the right box hurts my eyes ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Don't worry, it's easy to change. I hope you like it now. ;-) I've also improved the distance between first box and text.

Comment: I know how to change the background colour of a `tcolorbox` ;-) Yes, it's better now :D

Comment: this would look nicer with not as much blank space at the right side of the boxes, and slightly larger spaces around "or",

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fancyvrb` facilities. Note that the environment's contents should be typed at the left margin, due to the properties of verbatim.

Disadvantage: you have to adjust the spacing following the environment.

Advantage: you don't have to guess the width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{FBVerbatim}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
   \begin{lrbox}{\FBVerbatimbox}
   \begin{BVerbatim}}
  {\end{BVerbatim}
   \end{lrbox}
   \fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\usebox{\FBVerbatimbox}\end{tabular}}}

\newsavebox{\FBVerbatimbox}

\begin{document}

Either
\begin{FBVerbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\end{FBVerbatim}
\ or
\begin{FBVerbatim}
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\end{FBVerbatim}
\,.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, `\hbox` worked (but not `\savebox`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\end{verbatim}  
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\usebox0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But lrbox works ;-). However I think you mean `setbox` vs `savebox` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46480/setbox-vs-sbox-and-savebox-what-are-the-differences-i-need-to-know-about