# Box variable does not display its content

Tags: boxes, variable

I'd like to use box variables and cannot deal with this example:

```
\newsavebox{\abox}              % declared a variable of a box type
\sbox{\abox}{The block content} % abox := \hbox{The block content};
\abox
```

The output result is '9'... What's wrong?

The only where I succeeded is making a box variable with a 'picture':

```
\newsavebox{\abox}
\sbox{\abox}{\circle{30}}

\begin{picture}(50,50)
\multiput(10,30)(10,5){3}{\copy\abox} % or \usebox{\abox}
\end{picture}
```

Comment: You need \usebox\abox to use a box.

Comment: This question might be helpful: [\setbox vs. \sbox and \savebox - What are the differences I need to know about?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46480)